# AJAX JSON with ServiceStack

Tags: ajax, json, servicestack

I have spend over 10 hours trying to figure this out and looking at similar examples from other people but unfortunately I haven't been able to find out what's my problem here.

I have a ServiceStack Webservice setup:

```
http://example.com/v1/getuser?code=abcd&lastname=doe&format=json
```

If I run the above via the browser I will get the following:

```
[{"nameresult":"joe"}]
```

I am trying to get this via making an ajax call as follow:

```
   var code = $("#code_field").val();
   var lastname = $("#lastname_field").val();

   $.ajax({ 
     url: "http://example.com/v1/getuser",
     type: "POST",
     data: JSON.stringify({
       code: code,
       lastname: lastname,
       format: 'json'
     }),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success: function (data) {
     var returned_data = data;
       alert('returned_data=' + returned_data);
     },
     error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
       console.log('xhRequest: ' + xhRequest + "\n");
       console.log('ErrorText: ' + ErrorText + "\n");
       console.log('thrownError: ' + thrownError + "\n");
     }
   });
```

When I run the above, I get the following:

```
returned_data=[object Object]
```

Does anyone knows how could I get the json result, nameresult=joe? I am assuming that [object Object] contains [{"nameresult":"joe"}] but I am not entirely sure because I cannot see inside the object :(. thanks so much.

**LATEST UPDATE** - **PROBLEM SOLVED!**

I figured out the problem I was having. It had to do with ServiceStack and not with the Ajax call. My problems was the following, I hope it helps someone else one day that may face the same issue.

1.- I needed to enable CORS support on ServiceStack in order to allow posting parameters from Ajax:

```
File: AppHost.cs     
//Permit modern browsers (e.g. Firefox) to allow sending of any REST HTTP Method
        base.SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
        {
            GlobalResponseHeaders = {
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" },
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type" },
            },
        });

        Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());
        this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes, requestDto) =>
        {
            //Handles Request and closes Responses after emitting global HTTP Headers
            if (httpReq.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                httpRes.EndServiceStackRequest();  //httpExtensions method
            //  =>after  v.3.9.60, => httpRes.EndRequestWithNoContent(); 
        });
```

2.- My getuser method was in the GET instead of POST. I moved that to the POST and problem solved.

```
Moved getuser from here: public object Get(...) into here public object Post(...)
```

Thanks to all for helping me figure this out.

Comment: Use the `console`! It will display the full contents: `console.log(returned_data)`. If the result is `[{nameresult:"joe"}]` you can do `returned_data[0].nameresult` to get the value.

Comment: I am running the html within phonegap in an android app and I console.log doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You can serialize the object to a JSON string with `JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: I done the following now: success: function (data) {
                                        var returned_data = data;
                                        alert('returned_data=' + returned_data);
                                        alert('serialize=' + JSON.stringify(data));},  and I am getting this: serialize={} - So I am thinking that the problem maybe at how the data is been post to the server (data: JSON.stringify({
       code: code,
       lastname: lastname,
       format: 'json'
     }),

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log to output returned_data by itself:

```
console.log(returned_data);
```

This will display the JSON object:

```
{"nameresult":"joe"}
```

Your original alert concatenates the string "returned_data=" with the JSON object, and thus the object  is converted to a placeholder string "[object Object]" by the browser.

I often put my label in one log, and the object in another:

```
console.log('returned_data:');
console.log(returned_data);
```

Comment: I am running the html within phonegap in an android app and console.log doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: How are you debugging?

Comment: yes I tried to debug but I get no errors or messages :(. I am trying now to run a simple html file via firefox and see what I get

Comment: Your best bet is to get set up with remote debugging using Weinre. For Android, see: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews or this article: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap

Comment: thanks patrickfox, the thing is that I get the impression that the problem is somehow in the way I am posting the data to the server. The server is expecting code=abcd&lastname=doe&format=json but it could be that is getting this in the wrong format. I can run other ajax within phonegap without any problems so the problem. Before I look at the remote debugging, I am trying to see if I can verify that my syntax (data: JSON.stringify... is correct or not